# How to Query for Posts with 2 or more Comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

If i have the following:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end


class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

How do i query for posts that have 2 or more comments? I'd like to do this in the database rather than Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be extremely simply and probably faster if you set up a [counter cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache) on this association:

```
Post.where('comments_count >= ?', 2)
```

If you do not have this counter cache, you need to do something like:

```
Post.select('posts.*').joins(:comments).group('posts.id').
     having('COUNT(comments.id) >= ?', 2)
```